# Is it possible to construct a DFA that accepts the language of the empty set?

Tags: automata

[image]Construct a DFA that accepts the language of the empty set. The alphabet is 0 and 1. I think it is just one state with no accept states and one arrow with both inputs.

Comment: There would have to be two states.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think there has to be two states for the language of just the empty string.

Comment: Your DFA is correct

Comment: Any number of states works, as long as none of them is an accepting state.

Comment: "The language of just the empty string" is how I interpreted "the language of the empty set."